# Onclick is not working while using visual studio 2015 windows phone app

Tags: javascript

design

```
<div class="align_center">
    <div class="btn EmployeeloginBtn" **onclick="new Employee().register()**">REGISTER</div> 
</div>
```

Employee.js:

```
var Employee = function() {    
    var self = this;

    self.register = function ()
    {       
        var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
        var regSeven = /^7[0-9].*$/
        var regEight = /^8[0-9].*$/
        if($("#empId").val() =='')
        {
            alert("invalid emp id");
            return false;
        }
        if(mobile =='')
        {
            alert("invalid mob no");
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

When I click the button onclick is not working its not triggering to Employee.js

Comment: Do you have your js file linked to your html?

Comment: yes i linked the js in my html page. if i run in ie11 its working, i running through visual studio 2015 emulator 8.1 i m facing this issue

Comment: Is it working in other browsers?

Comment: no its not working in chrome or firefox or microsoft edge

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but it seems to me that in such an application it does not run the JavaScript code placed in the HTML file.

Here the `new Employee statement().Register()` is ignored.

Try to manage the button click directly in your JS file.

```
document.getElementById("Button1").onclick = function() {new Employee().register();};
```

and

```
<div id="Button1" class="btn EmployeeloginBtn">REGISTER</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to change the onclick attribute?

Test different ways...

```
<div class="btn EmployeeloginBtn" onclick="new Employee().register()">REGISTER</div>
```

Im not sure if there is a framework or something else that you need the '*'

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the OPs attempt to draw attention to a specific bit of code as actual code.